# How to use continue statement in a loop?

Tags: python

This is a code that takes a list of numbers from the user and computes the smallest and largest till he enters "done". Anytime the user enters an invalid input, this iteration should be skipped. I used `continue` in the loop to do this, but it doesn't work as I expect.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : break
    try:
        isinstance(num,int) == True
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue
    if largest is None :
        largest = num
    elif num > largest :
        largest = num
    if smallest is None :
        smallest = num
    elif num < smallest :
        smallest = num
print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

for instance, when using this list of inputs: `1`; `2`; `alex`; `9`; and `7`, this is the output that I've got:

```
Maximum is Alex
Minimum is 1
```

Comment: Your use of `continue` is not the problem. `isinstance(num,int) == True` is not the right way to try and convert your string to an int. You could use `num = int(num)` there instead.

Comment: I am not trying to convert the string input to an int. I am trying to test if it is a string and skip this iteration if it is true

Comment: No, it *is* a string. If the user types in `4` then you get the string `'4'` and you need to convert it to the number 4.

Comment: Are you using python 2.x or 3.x? The `input` function behaves differently in 2 (typing in 2 would return the integer 2) and 3 (typing in 2 would return the string '2'). Your `print` statement suggests python 3, but call it out specifically in your question or the tags.

Comment: Oh! i forgot about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This should work, except you are never actually converting the input to an `int`. I believe the return value from `input` will always be a string. That doesn't mean it can't be converted to an `int`, but it will be the string `"42"` instead of the int `42` at first. I would try:

Instead of `isinstance(num,int) == True` do `int_input = int(num)`. Your try/catch will catch if this doesn't work if num wasn't an int-like input. Note that your original `isinstance()` call will never raise an exception, it will just evaluate to `True` or `False`, so it will always proceed, which is why you are getting your strange results. Your continue is now in the right place. Then use `int_input` instead of `num` for the rest of your code, as you'll want to be dealing with the int, not the string input.

Here's an example:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        int_input = int(num)
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue
    if largest is None :
        largest = int_input
    elif int_input > largest :
        largest = int_input
    if smallest is None :
        smallest = int_input
    elif int_input < smallest :
        smallest = int_input
print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the statement `isinstance(num, int) == True` checks whether `num` is an integer, then throws away the answer. It never actually causes an error (unless the `isinstance` function itself has an internal error).

You probably want to use an `if` statement:

```
if not isinstance(num, int):
    print('Invalid input')
    continue
```

Secondly, as others have noted, the `input()` function will always return a string; when you gave the program `1`; `2`; `alex`; `9`; and `7`, it found the maximum and minimum in alphabetical order — or, rather the computer variant of alphabetical order, in which numbers come before letters.